# Could not find implicit value for parameter F: cats.Applicative[F]

Tags: scala, slick, scala-cats

I'm currently going through a tutorial on cats.

The tutorial gives me a repository of cat breads (uses Slick) which I'm not supposed to edit, then asks me to implement different methods. Unfortunately I'm stuck on something which seems pretty obvious.

I am given the method

```
  def findByName(name: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Option[Breed]] = {
    query.filter(_.name === name).result.headOption
  }
```

in `breedsRepository` and I'm supposed to implement the following method:

```
def findBreed(name: Either[Int, String]): DBIO[Either[Int, Breed]] = ???
```

I thought about:

```
def findBreed(name: Either[Int, String]): DBIO[Either[Int, Breed]] =
    name.traverse(n => breedsRepository.findByName(n).map(_.get))
```

But I get the error `could not find implicit value for parameter F: cats.Applicative[F]`
Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you importing appropriate Applicative instances in your context?

Comment: I think so. I `import cats.implicits._` and a dbio monad. Besids the imports where already there in all exercises and always correct.

Comment: Having `flatMap(..)` doesn't make something a `cats.Monad`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I should probably have said a cats dbio monad. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @Lukasz `cats` doesn't know about `DBIO`, `cats` doesn't depend on `slick`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code compiles:

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import cats.implicits._
import com.rms.miu.slickcats.DBIOInstances._

object breedsRepository {   
  case class Breed(name: String, price: Double)

  class BreedTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Breed](tag, "BREEDS") {
    def name = column[String]("NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
    def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
    def * = (name, price) <> (Breed.tupled, Breed.unapply)
  }
  val query = TableQuery[BreedTable]

  def findByName(name: String)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): DBIO[Option[Breed]] = {
    query.filter(_.name === name).result.headOption
  }

  def findBreed(name: Either[Int, String]): DBIO[Either[Int, Breed]] =
    name.traverse[DBIO, Int, Breed](n => findByName(n).map(_.get))
}
```

*build.sbt*

```
name := "slickdemo"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.3",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.3"
)

libraryDependencies += "org.typelevel" %% "cats-core" % "1.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.rms.miu" %% "slick-cats" % "0.7.1.1"
```